# Solving a Poisson Probability question

Tags: poisson-distribution

I need help in understanding what is meant by this question.

Given that:

λ = 0.2 incidents per week
X = incidents that occur in a 52-week
period.

Given that no incidents occur in the first 10 weeks, find the probability that at most 10 incidents occur in the following 42 weeks.

From my understanding, it seems the question wants me to do something like this:

A be event that incident occur in first 10 weeks
B be event that incident occur in following 42 weeks

P(B<=42|A=0) = P(A=0 and B<=42)/P(A=0)

Not sure if my understanding is correct right now.

Comment: You don't use $\lambda$ and $X$ in your question ; probably because you mix up events and variables.

Comment: Under the Poisson model, the number $Y$ of events in the first $10$ weeks and the number $X$ of events in the next $42$ are independent.

Comment: What do you mean by that Captain Lama? And how should I proceed with that? Most probably I still have to find P(X and Y)?